# AsyncTask does not stop if a long running loop is working in it?

Tags: android, runnable

friends,

i am using following code inside asyncTask

public class AsycLoaderFromDbAndMapInjector extends AsyncTask
    {

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


    }




   @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
         Log.d("Asynctask", ""+arg0);  

                boolean show = false;
                if(db == null)
                db = new dbHelper(me);

                ATM results = null;
                try {
                 results = db.getAtmsBySelectedBanks(atm.getSelectedBankList(), selectedCity);
                 if (results != null) {
                        LoopThroughEachATMToDisplayOnMap();
                    }

            return show;

    }


   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
       stopProgress();
    }
```

private void LoopThroughEachATMToDisplayOnMap()
       {

```
       Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.marker);
        itemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView);

        for (int i = 0; i < atm.getAtmList().size(); i++) {

            ATM a = atm.getAtmList().get(i);
            if (a != null) {
                int[] coordinates = getIntCoordinates(a
                        .getCoordinates());
                if (coordinates != null) {
                    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(coordinates[0],
                            coordinates[1]);
                    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(
                            point, a.getBankName(), a.getAddress()
                                    + "@@" + a.getPhone() + "@@"
                                    + a.getWebAddress() + "@@"
                                    + a.getCoordinates());
                    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
                    System.out
                            .println("coordinates-------------------------"
                                    + i + " "
                                    + coordinates[0]
                                    + ","
                                    + coordinates[1]);
                }

            }

        }


   }


}
```

now when i press back button this runable populate keeps running in the backend i have used

AsyncTask.cancel() on backbuttonpressed event but still it keeps running any one guide me how to solve this issue?

Comment: According to AsyncTask document, onPostExecute is executed on the UI thread. Invoking runOnUiThread from it will lead to the immediate execution of populate so it looks pretty difficult to stop it.
Cancelling the AsyncTask won't cancel the onPostExecute execution since it is executed by the UI thread.
It may be better to send a message to an Handler on onPostExecute, or delay the runnable execution.

Comment: Can you post the whole Async Task please?

Comment: You don't need to run it on the UI thread

Comment: edited my code actually LoopThroughEachATMToDisplayOnMap is long running function trying to display 600pins on map so it takes time and when user presses backbutton this loop still keeps running.

Comment: i have removed runonUIThread from onPostExecute()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
 private ATM results = null;
     @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
             Log.d("Asynctask", ""+arg0);  

                    boolean show = false;
                    if(db == null)
                    db = new dbHelper(me);

                    ATM results = null;
                    try {
                     results = db.getAtmsBySelectedBanks(atm.getSelectedBankList(), selectedCity);
                     if (results != null) {
                            publishProgress(0);
                      }

                return show;

        }



     @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                    if (results != null) {
                        LoopThroughEachATMToDisplayOnMap();
                    }
            }
```

set a flag in  LoopThroughEachATMToDisplayOnMap(), to stop the for loop when the back button is pressed.

That is,

Detect when the back button is pressed, set the condition variable.

Inside the loop through method there is a condition variable which will break the for loop.

Comment: thank you so much. this is what i was looking for actually i was expecting it should stop autmatically when i call cancel() of asycnTask. but it didnt.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to explicitly provide your populate runnable a way to detect that you don't want it to complete. Often people use Thread.interrupt() for this, but since your code doesn't fully control the UI thread that might not be a great idea here.